# java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object exception

Tags: java, rmi

There have been acouple of questions about this already, but their answers  suggest that the exported object has been GC'd on the server side and that is cousing the problems. However it seems like that this is not the issue here.

Mentioned exception is thrown only on single machine:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
```

With java:

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

This happend on the same machine with OpenJDK 7something as well.

According to other answers I am supposed to keep a strong reference to handling objects. I am doing it now, so what more can be done?

The same code works on windows as well as on a different remote linux machine with java 7. 
Any ideas why?

I have implemented some finalizers to the connected classes, but none of them are called.

As suggested I am using static references. As for me there is no way get exported object GC enligible. **Exception is thrown on remote method invocation right after object lookup.**

Piece of class

```
public class Client{
     //some fields
    private final int RMI_PORT;
    private static SearchTestServiceImpl searchTestService;
    private static Remote stub;
    private Registry registry;
    //and starting service
    public void startService() throws RemoteException {
        createRegistry();
        searchTestService = new SearchTestServiceImpl(name);
        stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(searchTestService, RMI_PORT + 1);
        registry.rebind(SearchTestService.class.getName(), stub);
        log.info("Binding {} to port {}", SearchTestService.class.getName(), RMI_PORT + 1);
    }

    private void createRegistry() throws RemoteException {
        log.info("Starting RMI registry on port {}", RMI_PORT);
        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(RMI_PORT);
        }

(...)
    }
```

And bootstrapping code

```
public class Bootstrap {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bootstrap.class);
    private static Client c;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, 
// some preparations
        c = new Client(Integer.valueOf(port), name);
        c.startService();
        System.gc();
        System.runFinalization();
        synchronized (c) {
            c.wait();
        }

    }
}
```

and stacktrace

```
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at call to a method of remote lookedup object #getName in this example.
```

Requested piece of code - lookup and call that throws exception

```
//somewhere

SearchTestService c = getClient(address); // this returns nice stub
String name = c.getName(); // this is throwing exception

private SearchTestService getClient(String string) throws NumberFormatException, RemoteException, NotBoundException {
    String[] parts = string.split(":");
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(parts[0], Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
    SearchTestService client = (SearchTestService) registry.lookup(SearchTestService.class.getName());
    return (SearchTestService) client;
}
```

Console output after running "listening" client side code (with RMI registry)

```
10:17:55.915 [main] INFO  pl.breeze.searchtest.client.Client - Starting RMI registry on port 12097
10:17:55.936 [main] INFO  p.b.s.client.SearchTestServiceImpl - Test agent Breeze Dev staging is up and running
10:17:55.952 [main] INFO  pl.breeze.searchtest.client.Client - Binding pl.choina.searchtest.remote.SearchTestService to port 12098
```

And this waits untill manuall shutdown - tested.

Comment: Is your server fetching something from database and returning it back to client? I think that might be the error means "no such object in table"

Comment: @BilboBaggins nope, no DAO here

Comment: @shekharsuman `SearchTestService.class` is an `interface extends Remote`. I will add lookup code to the post but remember, it works fine on 4 computers, but throwing exception on one.

Comment: @Antoniossss-Would you please share the code for your Remote interface `SearchTestService`? And, as EJP said, make the `private Registry registry;` static in your class Client! Also, please show what are you passing as **address**  in `SearchTestService c = getClient(address);`!

Comment: Address is a ip:port string. I will paste the interface code tomorrow. However I Dont think it is relevant. Again. This code works for multiple machines local and over network. However throws exception only on one of them

Answer (score 0):

```
NoSuchObjectException
```

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/NoSuchObjectException.html):

> A NoSuchObjectException is thrown if an attempt is made to invoke a method on an object that no longer exists in the remote virtual machine.

This means that the remote object referred to by the stub you are calling methods on has been unexported, i.e. the stub is 'stale'. The only way that can happen is by unexporting the object, either manually or as a result of GC.

> As suggested I am using static references.

No you're not. You need to make the `Registry` reference static. Otherwise you just form a cycle between `Client` and `Registry` that can be garbage-collected all at once.

Why you're calling your server `Client` is another mystery.

**EDIT** A few comments:

```
stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(searchTestService, RMI_PORT + 1);
```

There's no need to use a second port here. Just re-use the Registry port.

```
log.info("Binding {} to port {}", SearchTestService.class.getName(), RMI_PORT + 1);
```

This is misleading. You've already done both, but what you have done is:

1. Exported the object on the port, and
2. Bound the object to a name

in two separate steps.

```
System.gc();
System.runFinalization();
```

Strange things to be doing here, or indeed anywhere.

```
synchronized (c) {
    c.wait();
}
```

This isn't reliable. You don't really need anything here, as RMI should keep the JVM open as long as it has exported remote objects, but you could do what the Registry does:

```
while (true)
{
    Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

with the appropriate exception handling.

I can't reproduce your problem, but then I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: As for the mistery, this piece of code will be launched on multiple machines at the same time, controller will remote call clients ;) 
If registry would be GCd than I won't be able to lookup as I can now am I right? Besides this is first time I have to perform such hax, and I have made a dozen on RMI apps.

Comment: And one more thing, none of fields here are garbage collectable due to strong reference to `Client` object and holding monitor on it.

Comment: And FYI, static reference to `registry` did not change anything.

Comment: @shekharsuman Are you in doubt or you think that is the cause? Anyway - missing package = no compiled jar. Reflection is not used at all here.

Comment: And as I mentioned before - finalizers are not called so no garbage collection in this case.

Comment: If the registry gets GCd *after* the lookup it will release the remote reference to the 'client', which leads to DGC, etc. Anything that gets called in RMI I is a server, not a client, unless there are callbacks.

Comment: Leave naming convention in the project to me please. As for GC. This cannot be an issue as I have mentioned, static reference to registry, stub and remote object did not change anything. Moreover finalizer of remote obiect is not called at all so no gc issue here. The truth is, that i have no clue what could be the issue here

Comment: If it didn't get garbage-collected, somebody has called `unexportObject()` somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunetly this is not correct. In fact unexporting is newer called by design in my situation. I have seen that you have answered similar questions in that way, but for some reasons remote object is NOT GCd nor unexported and still getting the exception. Looks more like environement specific behaviour. Ill make a mory dump and check for avtive instance of remote object

Comment: Unfortunately this *is* correct. That is the meaning of the exception. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/rmi/NoSuchObjectException.html): "A NoSuchObjectException is thrown if an attempt is made to invoke a method on an object that no longer exists in the remote virtual machine." There is no other explanation. You may not be doing it yourself, but somebody is.

Comment: Got it. The clients are ran simultaniously on 4 machines right now. I can work with 3 of them in parallel (that is the whole point of the application) but the 4th is giving me exception. Apps are ran with the same start parameters (expect the "name"). By somebody you mean a person or other piece of code? No other persons involved in this:)

Comment: I mean almost certainly the JRE itself, via garbage collection. I'm curious about your remark about finalisers not being run. How do you know that?

Comment: By overriding `finalize` method of the remote object and sysouting the info. Tested on following (pseudo) code ` Remote r=new Remote(); r=null; System.gc()" - this placed right before Object#wait() in bootrapping class, so even AFTER exposing remote via RMI fires finalizer but only ONCE.

Comment: Is your` Bootstrap` class exiting? Try `Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` in a `while (true)` loop. You never know who is going to be notifying your objects. And why is it calling `System.gc()` and `System.runFinalization()`? Strange things to do any time.

Comment: This is added for debugging - i tried to force GC to check if my remote handler object is indeed GCd. Bootstrap is not exiting, it is waitinig and not getting notified by anything as expected. If Bootstrap would exit, I wouldn't be able to lookup as well, cuz the RMIRegistry would be down right? I have ran the same code on Amazon EC2. 10 free instances - 2 of 10 gave me the same behaviour.

Comment: As for the code - `stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(searchTestService, RMI_PORT + 1); ` this is needed for port forwarding - I cannot use random port, thats why it is defined as it is, as next to the RMI port.

Comment: As for exiting bootstrap main method - I have added console output to the question.

Comment: What is this is not a RMI server side problem, but client side? I am storing lookups in a collection. Maybe I should lookup everytime? Normaly I do in my other RMI projects.